# OPENSTACK linux-bridge agent

Tags: openstack

Following the installation guide for Newton on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS, when I run **openstack network agent list** on the controller, I see the DHCP agent and the metadata agent, but the linuxbridge agent doesn't show up on either the controller node nor on the compute node.here is

What I am supposed to have :

[image]

what i actually have :

[image]

Comment: You posted the same image twice, but regardless you will probably need to post more information from `/var/log/*` to debug further. A good starting point is to check your `/etc/nova/nova.conf` and your neturon config file for typos. (and restart the services).

Comment: this log in particular may be helpful: `/var/log/neutron/linuxbridge-agent.log`

Comment: hi Amarnasan , i didnt know about the duplicated photo , infact i did the installation from scratch and every thing went well . sorry i didnt post it till today

Comment: There’s only 2 reason you are not seeing the linuxbridge-agent. 1. You haven’t installed them or 2. You haven’t configured them correctly. Yes, the nova logs must be helpful. If you have linuxbridge-agent installed, troubleshoot from the logs such as /var/log/neutron/plugins/linuxbridge-agen.....